# A way to create a mssql database if it does not exist with sequelize.sync()?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a database with sequelize if one doesn't exist;
I created am initial migration with the following code.

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const {database, username, password, dialect} = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const sequelize = new Sequelize("", username, password, {
      dialect: dialect,
    });

    return sequelize.query(`CREATE DATABASE '${database}';`);
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    queryInterface.dropDatabase(database);
  }
};
```

And then call it in the index.js file.

```
sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Database & tables created!`)
  });
```

When I try and run it I get the following error "Unhandled rejection SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Login failed for user 'sa'."

However if I create the database using SQLPro it connects without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to do this via sequelize; however, I was able to resolve it using the mssql npm module. Here was my solution:

```
//code in my index.js for sequelize
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const mssql = require('mssql');

//set up connection
const pool = new mssql.ConnectionPool({
  user: config.username,
  password: config.password,
  server: 'localhost',
});

//create database if one does not exist
pool.connect(error => {
  if(error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    pool.query(`IF DB_ID('${config.database}') IS NULL CREATE DATABASE ${config.database}`);
  }
});
```

I am still interested if you can do something similar with sequelize. If anyone has found a way using only sequelize please let me know.

Thanks!